# Use a variable string as object parameter in python

Tags: python

How to call for the object parameter if the parameter is a variable string. In this case is variable beacuse it is the header in a database
`column_header = "variable string"`

`lambda rec: (rec.column_header)`
another case
`item.column_header = new_value`

Comment: What do you mean by "object parameter"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- To read a property from a string as name use `getattr()`

  ```
  getattr(obj, name)
  ```
- To set a property from a string as name use `setattr()`

  ```
  setattr(obj, name, value)
  ```

---

In your case it'd mean

- Get

  ```
  column_header = "variable string"
  lambda rec: getattr(rec, column_header)
  ```
- Set

  ```
  column_header = "variable string"
  setattr(item, column_header, new_value)
  ```